# AJAX call without button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, stripe-payments

Usually when a value need to be passed to `php`, it is a result from a button click or form submit. However, I am generating my values from a stripe `handler`. How can I use `AJAX` to `POST` to `.php` without `button` or `form` tag.?

This is what I have so far but no luck.

```
      var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: 'stripe_test_key',
        image: "./img/my_image.png",
        locale: 'auto',
        token: function(token) {

            alert(token.id);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'myphp.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { MyToken: token.id, MyEmail: token.email}
            });
        }
    });
```

When I run this code, I am only able to see the alert which shows my token id. I have an `echo` at the beginning of my php file but it does not show the message.

I am using Stripe Payments and I actually am clicking an `img` to `show` the `handler`, but there has to be a way to pass my values to `php` when I sucessfully get my token without having to detect an `img` click event.

Comment: #1) open your developer tools (F12) and go to the network tab.  Make the alert happen.  After it's done, verify that the ajax request was made.  #2) Verify by clicking on the request in the network tab that all the query params on it are correct.  #3) How are you trying to access the `MyToken` in the PHP?

Comment: "I have an echo at the beginning of my php file but it does not show the message"...that's because you haven't written any code in the Javascript to receive the response from the ajax request and do anything with it. Since you called the PHP via AJAX, anything you echo in the PHP is returned to the ajax call and is held in a JS variable (available through a callback function which runs when the call succeeds and a response is received from the server). The echo'd data does not show on the screen in your browser automatically - because your browser is already showing a different page!

Comment: As a really simple example, to see what your myphp.php file outputs (assuming the ajax request succeeds), replace your current ajax call with `$.ajax({
                url: 'myphp.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { MyToken: token.id, MyEmail: token.email}
            }).done(function(response) { alert(response); });` (If the ajax request fails, it's possible to write code to deal with that, but for now just look a the console and network tools in your developer tools, and it'll display some error info)

Comment: P.S. even without writing that extra code, you can already see what the PHP outputs by watching the ajax request in your network tool (as Taplar described) - if you click into the request there will be a "Response" tab showing any data returned by the server. It seems you perhaps haven't yet got to grips with the basic concepts of AJAX and also how to debug your JS code. Now would be a great time to increase your knowledge :-)

Comment: the shortcut is usually browser-specific rather than platform-specific. Although within that there may be platform-specific shortcuts for cross-platform browsers. e.g. here's the list of shortcuts for Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts . You can see the mac equivalent of F12 in Chrome is Command+Option+I. Remember the network tools must be opened **before** the ajax code runs, or else you won't see anything.

Comment: P.S. All the major browser vendors have decent documentation of their dev tools, showing what they're capable of. Your browser, unknown to most people of course, is practically a fully-fledged IDE under the hood.

Comment: @ADyson interesting. After looking in the logs, I got a `POST https://myurl.com/myphp.php 500 (Internal Server Error)` These errors for this specific crash aren't too helpful though.

Comment: Yeah a 500 is just a generic error not designed to give too much away. To get the real error message you need to look in your PHP logs on the server (or switch on PHP error reporting and run the code again)

Comment: Yes, I was able to figure it out. Turns out in my `my.php` file. I had a `require_once()` which referenced another php file. But the files being referenced in that php file were not even uploaded to the server.